# DuplicateHandle in WINAPI returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: winapi

I have two anonymous pipe handles. I want to pass one of them to a child process.
It works correctly if I call `DuplicateHandle` to make the handle inheritable for a write handle of the pipe like:

```
DuplicateHandle(myHandle, fdCP[1], myHandle, &fdCP[1], DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS, 1, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE);
```

However when doing it for a read handle of another pipe I get a `0x00000000` value in the result handle.

`GetLastError` in this case is 5 (`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`). I tried to provide `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` of `GENERIC_ALL|SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL` when created the pipe. However it didn't help.

I noted that `DuplicateHandle` works as expected if called in on the read handle as follows:

```
DuplicateHandle(myHandle, fdPC[0], myHandle, &fdPC[0], 0, 1, DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE | DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
```

In both cases myHandle is `GetCurrentProcess()`.

So the question is this an error in WINAPI? And is this a correct workaround?

Comment: Q: Is this an error in WINAPI? A: No.

Comment: Never tried this myself.  I think it is safe to assume that Windows is stopping you from doing something foolish.  Assume this will work.  Who is going to get the data from the pipe when another thread calls ReadFile() at the same time?  And no, "both" is not the way a pipe works, it doesn't buffer unread data for a handle.

Comment: I have 4 handles (for two pipes) for exchange of data between child and parent. Parent writes to child through his write end and child inherits read handle while parent closes it when child has started. Also child writes to parent through his write end and parent reads data using the read handle. Both reads are executed in separate threads in parent and child processes.

Comment: Oh, I thing I understand what I did wrong. Simply I mistook what was written in the documentation, since DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS is possible only in dwOptions argument while it's always treated as access rights in a dwDesiredAccess argument.